# how to split a string across '\' using split function?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I am newbie for java language.
I am want to split the string "mandar\jitendra\sadye" to 3 strings "mandar","jitendra" and "sadye" using split function in string library.
The program that I use to split the string is as follow:

```
public class string 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String mandar="mandar\\jitendra\\saye";
        String[] words=mandar.split("[\\]");
        for(int a=0;a<words.length;a++)
        {
            System.out.println(words[a]);
        }
    }
}
```

But this program gives this error[image: image of error from command prompt]
If i replace '\' by any other escape sequence like'\0' then program runs just fine[image: output when '\' is replaced by '\0']
I already tried using ['\'] [] [\] ['\'] [\] but none of these tokens are working for me.
So is there a some special way for for splitting a string across '\'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the `\` correctly. Once for java, again for regex engine.

```
    String mandar="mandar\\jitendra\\saye";
    String[] words=mandar.split("\\\\");
    for(int a=0;a<words.length;a++)
    {
        System.out.println(words[a]);
    }
```

O/P :

```
mandar
jitendra
saye
```

Another approach I would think about is using `Pattern.quote()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String mandar="mandar\\jitendra\\saye";
    String[] words=mandar.split(Pattern.quote("\\"));
    for(int a=0;a<words.length;a++)
    {
        System.out.println(words[a]);
    }
}
```

O/P :

```
mandar
jitendra
saye
```